# Default imports after publishing a NPM package

Tags: typescript, npm, import

Suppose I am writing some Typescript and in my `index.ts` I have something like this:

```
import { Something } from './something';
export default Something;
```

Then this gets compiled to:

```
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var something_1 = require("./something");
exports.default = something_1.Something;
```

Now suppose I publish this to NPM and everything goes well. I install this package and then I initiate a new project to test this thing, so I run `npm init -y` and create a simple `index.js` like this:

```
import Something from "my-npm-package"
console.log(Something);
```

This prints out:

```
{ default: [Function: _default] }
```

So in order to use `Something` I have to actually say:

```
const actuallySomething = Something.default;
```

So how do I simply get `Something.default` without the `.default` part?

UPDATE:
The `package.json` from my NPM package is here: https://github.com/DavidArmendariz/identity-number-validator/blob/master/package.json

I also know that if I transpile my code with Babel by simply doing this:

```
npx babel index.js -o out.js
```

And then run

```
node out.js
```

Then everything works as expected. But is there any way to do this without Babel? For example, if you install `lodash` you will be able to import the functions like this:

```
import _ from "lodash"
const example = [1,2,3]
_.map(example, function(n) { n*n })
```

And that's because `lodash` "exports" the functions right away (I really don't know how this is done, or if Typescript alone is not sufficient to do this)

Comment: can you share your package.json?

Comment: @John I have added the package.json from my NPM package, the other package.json is the one that comes by default when you run `npm init -y`. I also added an update.